# Header links: with or without type declaration?

Tags: html

Quick question: it has been standard practice to specify html header links like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainstylesheet.css"  type="text/css" />
```

But I have started seeing people removing such type declarations; particularly in projects such as html5 boilerplate.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainstylesheet.css"/>
```

Are these type declarations superfluous then, or is it still preferable to include them. Note; I don't mean can we get by without using them (which the answer would be 'yes') but rather which is better practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer removing `type` attribute from `link[rel="stylesheet"]` as well as `script` tags to save a few bytes, because it works without `type` and [its not obligatory](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=feed#attr-link-type) for links (for stylesheet links "text/css" [is the default](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=feed#link-type-stylesheet) and for script tags "text/javascript" [is the default](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=feed#attr-script-type))

Comment: Although not obligatory (provided that such external links are using the correct MIME types), the documentation says that such declaration provides hints to the parser (browser) that the resources are what they say they are. Is this in any real sense beneficial? (I mean there is nothing stopping someone from linking to an incorrect MIME type but specifying that it is a correct type in the link information)

Comment: I haven't tested the case of serving CSS file with incorrect MIME type. But I've used `type="text/template"` on `script` tags to store javascript templates in them.